# How to create swipe navigation in iOS (in Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I want to build swipe navigation like the one shown in these pics. There are total 4 headings placed horizontally.

[swipe navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymEYG.gif)

They are as follows.

1. "History"
2. "Rules"
3. "PRO"
4. "Terms And Conditions"

If i am reading "History" & swipe from right to left, then the "Rules" should be displayed.

And if am on "Rules", and swipe from left to right then it should display "History"

Can anyone please guide me how to do this ?

Thanks.

Comment: This is what exactly you want.
https://github.com/maxep/MXSegmentedPager

Comment: Use storyboard example for easier implementation.

Comment: Thanks @Rushisangani .....thats what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The link you posted is a static screenshot, and not very helpful in describing what you want to do.

I think what you are describing is a normal behavior for a `UIPageViewController`, set up for a slide transition rather than a page curl transition.

Do a search on "PhotoScroller" in Xcode. That will point to a demo app that illustrates the effect I think you are after. That app is more complex than you need as it supports pinch zooming and tiled rendering of pictures, but you can ignore that stuff.

Comment: thanks @duncan ..... i will check UIPageViewController. And didn't know how to create animated gif. Henceforth i will upload animated gif if necessary. Thanks once again :)

Answer (score 0):

I too would recommend a UIPageViewController. Here is a bare bones implementation:

```
@interface SwipeViewController : UIViewController <UIPageViewControllerDataSource>

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIPageViewController *pageViewController;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray <UIViewController*> *viewControllers;

@end

@implementation SwipeViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // add page view controller
    [self.pageViewController willMoveToParentViewController:self];
    [self.view addSubview:self.pageViewController.view];
    [self addChildViewController:self.pageViewController];
    [self.pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    // set the first view controller as the displayed view controllers (requires an array of exactly one view controller)
    [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:@[self.viewControllers.firstObject] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];
}

// array of 4 random colored view controllers
- (NSArray <UIViewController*>*)viewControllers {
    if (!_viewControllers) {
        _viewControllers = ({
            NSMutableArray *viewControllers = [NSMutableArray new];
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                UIViewController *aViewController = [UIViewController new];
                aViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(arc4random()%255)/255. green:(arc4random()%255)/255. blue:(arc4random()%255)/255. alpha:1];
                [viewControllers addObject:aViewController];
            }
            viewControllers;
        });
    }
    return _viewControllers;
}

- (UIPageViewController *)pageViewController {
    if (!_pageViewController) {
        _pageViewController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil];
        _pageViewController.dataSource = self;
    }
    return _pageViewController;
}

- (nullable UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    NSInteger index = [self.viewControllers indexOfObject:viewController];
    return index > 0 ? self.viewControllers[index-1] : nil;
}

- (nullable UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    NSInteger index = [self.viewControllers indexOfObject:viewController];
    return index + 1 < self.viewControllers.count ? self.viewControllers[index+1] : nil;
}

@end
```

Comment: thanks @casey ...i will try this in couple of hours and get back.